# NameError: name 'last_days' is not defined | trying to divide

Tags: python-3.x, calculator, divide

I've been googling for 30 minutes but I can't find a solution to my problem.
Please help!

```
import math

amount = input("Enter amount of medicine left: ")
dose = input("Enter dose per day: ")

def convertString(str):
    try:
        returnValue = int(str)
    except ValueError:
        returnValue = float(str)
    return returnValue

def count_days(amount, dose):
    last_days = amount / dose
    return last_days

print("Your medicine will run out in ",last_days," days.")
```

I get this error:
NameError: name 'last_days' is not defined

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Could you write `print ("Your medicine will run out in ",count_days(amount, dose)," days.")` instead? (I'm not a python coder.) It looks like you're defining a method, but not calling it.

Comment: I edited the code a bit.

Comment: The rest of the comment still stands - it looks like the `last_days` variable only exists within a `count_days` method. Have you tried calling the method as I described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `last_days` is *local* within the `count_days` function. That means that as soon as the function ends, the variable is no longer available. That is however not a problem as the function actually *returns* that value, making it available for others.

So when you do `my_var = count_days(amount, dose)`, then the function will execute, and return its `last_days` result which is then stored in `my_var`.

```
last_days = count_days(amount, dose)
print("Your medicine will run out in ", last_days, " days.")
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to   print("Your medicine will run out in ",count_days(amount, dose)," days.")

Answer (score 0):

`last_days` is defined just within `count_days`. Initialise the variable on top of the file to change the visibility

Comment: Declaring the variable at the beginning will *not* make the `last_days` variable inside of the function global. And it also shouldn’t be global to begin with.